# How to open a resource at specified line in Eclipse (in one step)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am looking for a built-in feature or plugin for Eclipse to do the following:

- Open Resource + Jump to Line (in one step)

Ideal would be to do this:

- Open Resource (Ctrl+Shift+R)
- Type: FileName:LineNumber (eg. test.html:50)

I know i can do it in 2 steps, but when copying "File:Line" from somewhere i need to paste it in "Open Resource", copy or memorize and delete the line-number, open the file and then invoke "Go to line" (Ctrl+L) and paste or type the line number and confirm. This is very complicated.

It would be great if the "Open resource" dialog could combine these steps.

Is there a built-in feature or plugin for Eclipse that can do this?

If not could anybody write such a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eclipse's 'Open from clipboard' navigation option. In Mac, the keyboard shortcut is Command+Shift+V. To use this option copy the java file and line number as it appears in the stackframe and press Command+Shift+V. The file should open at the specified line.
You can change the keybinding in eclipse preferences

Read eclipse's documentation for navigation menu actions
[Open from clipboard](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-navigate.htm) :

> *Open from clipboard* Tries to open the matching Java element in the editor if the clipboard contains a single line. Otherwise it opens the contents in the Java Stack Trace Console. Examples:
>
> - java.lang.String
> - String
> - String#getBytes
> - String.getBytes
> - java.lang.String.getBytes(String)
> - String.java:123
> - at java.lang.String.matches(String.java:1550)
> - java.lang.String.valueOf(char) line: 1456
> - currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 1):

The Open Resource dialog does not have such feature. If you think this is a generally useful feature you should open an [enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform)

Writing an external plug-in that provides this feature would be hard as the Open Resource dialog isn't meant to be extended.

In the meanwhile you'd have to hit two more keys:

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd> test.html <kbd>Return</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> 50 <kbd>Return</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear answer and especially the link to `enhancement request`.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped. Please post the link here if you open an enhancement request.